# What kind of vector calculus function do I need for this problem?

Tags: calculus

I am currently working on a project involving data trends. The table below shows the value of each activity--music, DJ, break-dancing, art graffiti--showing how popular each one is and how they change overtime in a 9-year interval.

I am looking for a vector calculus function that calculate the changes of each, and also looking for a function that would give approximate value for the next 9 years. Any suggestions? I highly appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: This is a time series analysis problem not a calculus problem. Look into time series modeling and forecasting.

Comment: Calculus is used for probability and statistics. Forecasting is good, but my project must have calculus elements.

Comment: [Numerical Recipes has two chapters](http://numerical.recipes) ( $14$ and $15$ ) which are dedicated to data analysis.

Comment: You can read the [NR old version here](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html). Don't worry for "$\mathsf{old}$". The theory is $\texttt{0 k.}$.

Comment: Why not do least squares fit to each series? That will use derivatives.